# Javascript: Fuzzily find substring in string

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a set of strings, and I need to fuzzily find whether one of these strings is included in a sentence. And if so, I need the position of the substring in the sentence.
For instance:

`var input = "how was the whether in Londom last night?";
var set = ["london uk", "paris"];
fuzzyFind(input, set); // return something like {score: xxx, found: "london uk", start: 23, end: 29}`

http://fusejs.io/ can do something like this it seems, but unless I missed it it won't tell me where in the input string the substring has been located.

Is there an existing library to do this (it will be used in Node)?

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/package/bitap

Comment: Thanks @smcd. Unfortunately it does not seem to do what I am after. For instance, it does not seem to return the indexes between which the searched string was found in the input text.

Answer (score -1):

Make sure the `include: ["matches"]` option is set.

Edit: That should be `include: ["score","matches"]`, and then in the results each result object will have a "matches" and a "score" property. And matches will be a list of "indices" for each item key with a start and end position for each match.

Also, the answer I had written up before I noticed that those options were in fuse.js was a version of the partial_ratio function from [fuzzball.js](https://github.com/nol13/fuzzball.js) (my fuzzywuzzy port) along with [difflib](https://github.com/qiao/difflib.js), modified to include the best matching substring of the longer string and its start/end position along with the score/ratio.

And since on second look my first answer isn't exactly what you were looking for, and was downvoted anyway, and I already have it written, here's that too :)

```
var difflib = require('difflib');

var input = "how was the whether in Londom last night?";
var set = ["london uk", "paris"];
console.log(topSubString(input, set));

/* 
[score, best matching substring, start, stop]

[ [ 0.5555555555555556, 'Londom la', 23, 32 ],
  [ 0.4, 'was t', 4, 9 ] ]
*/

function topSubString(input, set) {
    results = [];
    for (var s in set) {
        results.push(partial_ratio(input, set[s]));
    }
    results.sort(function (a, b) { return b[0] - a[0] })[0];
    return results;
}
function partial_ratio(str1, str2, options) {

    if (str1.length <= str2.length) {
        var shorter = str1
        var longer = str2
    }
    else {
        var shorter = str2
        var longer = str1
    }
    var bestMatch;
    var m = new difflib.SequenceMatcher(null, shorter, longer);
    var blocks = m.getMatchingBlocks();
    var scores = [];
    for (var b = 0; b < blocks.length; b++) {
        var long_start = (blocks[b][1] - blocks[b][0]) > 0 ? (blocks[b][1] - blocks[b][0]) : 0;
        var long_end = long_start + shorter.length;
        var long_substr = longer.substring(long_start, long_end);
        var ssm = new difflib.SequenceMatcher(null, shorter, long_substr);
        var r = ssm.ratio(shorter, long_substr, options);
        if (r > 99.5) { bestMatch = [r, long_substr, long_start, long_end]; break; }
        else scores.push([r, long_substr, long_start, long_end]);
    }
    if (!bestMatch) bestMatch = scores.sort(function(a,b){ return b[0] - a[0] })[0];
    return bestMatch;
}
```